# Tracking the progress of loadTransferable of a PhotosPickerItem

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, key-value-observing

I am loading a video from the user's photo library. I want to track the progress of `loadTransferable` to update a progress view. However, I am having a ton of trouble observing the key values.

I have tried creating an observable object as well, but I can never get the code in the `observe` closure to run.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

```
import SwiftUI
import Photos
import PhotosUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedVideo: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
     
    private func processSelectedVideo() {
        let progress = selectedVideo!.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) { result in
            Task {
                // do something
            }
        }
        observation = progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted, changeHandler: { progress, value in
            // this never runs
            print(value)
        })
        progress.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't have much to work with when it comes to your code - this is a very small snippet of what we would need to begin debugging. There are a few articles out there that touch on how we can use the `loadTransferable` for videos, but none of them are completely flushed out. I actually just wrote about this because I wanted to tackle getting a video to load (since I already understood photo loading) - you can view it here if you want help understanding how it works: https://yonmontoto.com/Loading-and-Displaying-Videos-in-SwiftUI-with-iOS-17-Transferable-Protocol/